# asp.net map.RunSignalR thread block

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

i have signalR in my asp.net MVC 5 app with .net 4.6 configured to allow cross domain. In debug i use local IIS because i have 3 website that interact with each other.

Sometime when debugging the process IIS Worker Process(w3wp.exe) can't be attached to debug. So i have to end the task and it work ... but i have discover an issue in production when i open 2 window, it seem the thread is blocked until i close the other window.

After attaching a debug session to this process when it dont respond, i have find the thread blocked at map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration); .

I can't find where the problem is.

If someone can point me on how to debug this, it will be verry nice :)

Version of signalR: 2.2.0
Version of Microsoft.Asp.Net.SignalR.Owin : 1.2.2

Declaration of signalR:

```
 private static readonly Lazy<CorsOptions> SignalrCorsOptions = new Lazy<CorsOptions>(() =>
    {
        return new CorsOptions
        {
            PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider
            {
                PolicyResolver = context =>
                {
                    var policy = new CorsPolicy();
                    policy.AllowAnyOrigin = true;
                    policy.AllowAnyMethod = true;
                    policy.AllowAnyHeader = true;
                    policy.SupportsCredentials = false;
                    return Task.FromResult(policy);
                }
            }
        };
    });

    app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            // Setup the CORS middleware to run before SignalR.
            // By default this will allow all origins. You can 
            // configure the set of origins and/or http verbs by
            // providing a cors options with a different policy.


            map.UseCors(SignalrCorsOptions.Value);
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
                // You can enable JSONP by uncommenting line below.
                // JSONP requests are insecure but some older browsers (and some
                // versions of IE) require JSONP to work cross domain
                EnableJSONP = true
            };
            // Run the SignalR pipeline. We're not using MapSignalR
            // since this branch already runs under the "/signalr"
            // path.
            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });
```

**UPDATE:**

I did not find a way to solve this, but i have patched it.
when im in debug, i wrap this in a task like this:

```
#if (DEBUG)
    public async void ConfigureSignalR(IAppBuilder app)
    {
#else
    public void ConfigureSignalR(IAppBuilder app)
    {
#endif

#if (DEBUG)
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
#endif
        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
                {
                ...
                }
#if (DEBUG)
        }
#endif
```

so, this prevent thread block. I can debug my application without to always have to terminate the process. When this bug happen, signalR dont respond. Just remember to terminate the process if you need to debug signalR code ...

hope this help some one.

ps. I am still looking a solution, but this "Patch" work ...

Comment: I wonder if this can be this: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3414

Comment: tanks, i did find this on my search. Seem to be signalR problem...
I will look for an update ;-)